# How to edit Cordova Multi-Hybrid App iOS UIViewController Source

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2013, ios-simulator, hybrid-mobile-app

How can I edit the iOS code generated by the Visual Studio Multi-Hybrid App Cordova plugin?  Each time that I compile and run the project on iOS, a new project folder is generated on the Mac host.  The problem is that the status bar on the iOS project overlaps the app background.  I can fix this issue by editing MainViewController.m on the Mac, but the edits that I make are not saved if I run the app from Windows Visual Studio again.

What must be done to change the MainViewController.m source files that are generated by Cordova each time the app is run?  I have tried adding an edited MainViewController.m file to the merges/ios directory in Visual Studio, but the file does not override the  MainViewController.m file that is generated on each build.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Here is the code that I am trying to add to the generated MainViewController.m so that the status bar does not overlap the app background:

`- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // View defaults to full size.  If you want to customize the view's size, or its subviews (e.g. webView),
    // you can do so here.
    // Lower screen 20px on ios 7
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
        CGRect viewBounds = [self.webView bounds];
        viewBounds.origin.y = 20;
        viewBounds.size.height = viewBounds.size.height - 20;
        self.webView.frame = viewBounds;
    }
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}`